# Jquery - find the parent element and then select another element inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a form validator. I did it first with javascript which was working. now i am using jquery so i am updating my code. but i can't update this function. this function should get the parent element of the input and select the small element within it.

How can I do this?

Javascript

```
const showError = (input, message) => {
    const formControl = input.parentElement
    formControl.className = 'form-control error'
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small')
    small.innerText = message
}
```

Jquery

```
const showError = (input, message) => {
    const formControl = input.parent()
    const small = $(`.${formControl} small`)
    small.addClass('text-danger')
    small.innerText = message
}
```

Comment: try wrap `input` in `$()` as `$(input).parent()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Now it shows `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .[object Object] small`

Comment: Then you can use `const small = formControl.find(`small`)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yep, it worked. thanks for your help :)

Comment: @yikemop651 no problem

Comment: @TheFool I love to work with vanilla javascript. but sometimes JQuery is quick